# How to warn user before leaving page but not on redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some pages on my site that allow users to create and edit posts. When a user is on these pages, I'd like to warn them before leaving the page. I can do that like this:

```
//Only warn if user is on a New or Edit page
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/new") !== -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit") !== -1  {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = '';
            });

//Doing this again because I don't know which version is compataible with all browsers
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = ''
            };
        };
```

On a `New` or `Edit` page, the information in a `form` gets submitted to the server using JQuery `ajax`. The server returns a URL which the user gets redirected to to see the results of their post/update like this `window.location.href = result;` with `result` being the URL sent back from the server.

When that code runs to do the redirect, the user is getting the warning that they are about to leave the page they are on. I don't want it to do this on any redirects/navigation that the user has not performed. How could I stop/remove the warning in this instances?

**UPDATE: This is not a duplicate. This question asks about preventing a `beforeunload`event happening on a redirect where the user has not requested to move away from the page himself.**

Comment: It would also help if you read the link that the duplicate points to and try out the solution there, because that question's answer is the answer to your problem here. `beforeunload` doesn't trigger unless the user initiates the navigation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus How is it when the other answer simply says how to display a confirm dialog when a user navigates away from the page. I am talking about preventing the dialog from appearing on a AJAX redirect. There is no solution on that other answer.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the `beforeunload` event registration without any `if/then` logic and just with `.addEventListener()` instead of also with the `onbeforeunload` property?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Can you cite your source for "beforeunload doesn't trigger unless the user initiates the navigation"? I can't find any documentation to that effect, but the OP wouldn't be having this problem if it were true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you may want the event bound in some circumstances but not others within the same `window`, you'll have to not only add the event handler to the `window`, but you'll have to remove it as well (under the right circumstance) because even though you are changing the URL of the `document` loaded in the `window`, you are not changing the `window` itself:

```
function handleBeforeUnload (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
}

//Only warn if user is on a New or Edit page
if(location.href.indexOf("/new") !== -1 || location.href.indexOf("/edit") !== -1  {
   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
} else {
   // Remove the previously registered event handler (if any)
   window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a navigation with `window.location.href`, you should disable the `beforeunload` event listener before you navigate.

Something like this, for example:

```
function unloadHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', unloadHandler);

function forceNavigation(url) {
    // Remove the "are you sure you want to leave?" message, then navigate
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', unloadHandler);
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Call `forceNavigation('https://example.com')` to navigate without warning the user.

JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o918wsam/1/